# I couldn't create entity inner join

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I got 3 table

```
**ODEME_ISLEM**
 odeme_islem_id (int)
 taksit_id (int)

**TAKSIT**
 taksit_id (int)

**TAKSIT_ISLEM**
 taksit_islem_id (int)
 taksit_id (int)
 vade_tarihi (date)
 taksit_tutar (decimal)
```

And I'm trying to convert below code to entity but I couldn't do it yet.

```
SELECT ODEME_ISLEM.ODEME_ISLEM_ID
FROM ODEME_ISLEM 
  INNER JOIN TAKSIT ON ODEME_ISLEM.TAKSIT_ID = TAKSIT.TAKSIT_ID 
  INNER JOIN TAKSIT_ISLEM ON TAKSIT.TAKSIT_ID = TAKSIT_ISLEM.TAKSIT_ID
WHERE (TAKSIT_ISLEM.TAHSILAT = 0)
  AND (TAKSIT_ISLEM.VADE_TARIHI > '2016-06-01')
  AND (TAKSIT_ISLEM.VADE_TARIHI < '2016-07-01')
```

I need odemeIslem object

Comment: do you have a table called TAKSIT too? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your entity models and DbContext is set-up but:

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-06-01");
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-07-01");

var query = from oi in db.OdemeIslem
            join t in db.Taksit on oi.TaskitId equals t.TaskitId
            join ti in db.TaksitIslem on t.TaskitId equals ti.TaskitId
            where ti.Tahsilat == 0 && ti.VadeTarihi > startDate && ti.VadeTarihi < endDate
            select oi.OdemeIslemId;
```